# How to make ordered dictionary from list of lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.7, ordereddictionary

The problem is:
Having a list of names, and a list of lists, how to create a list, in which each item is an ordered dictionary with names as keys, and items from list of lists as values? It might be more clear from code below:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

list_of_lists = [
                ['20010103', '0.9507', '0.9569', '0.9262', '0.9271'],
                ['20010104', '0.9271', '0.9515', '0.9269', '0.9507'],
                ['20010105', '0.9507', '0.9591', '0.9464', '0.9575'],
                ]

names = ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']
```

I would like to get:

```
ordered_dictionary = [
                     OrderedDict([('date', '20010103'), ('open', '0.9507'), ('high', '0.9569'), ('low', '0.9262'), ('close', '0.9271')]),
                     OrderedDict([('date', '20010104'), ('open', '0.9271'), ('high', '0.9515'), ('low', '0.9269'), ('close', '0.9507')]),
                     OrderedDict([('date', '20010105'), ('open', '0.9507'), ('high', '0.9591'), ('low', '0.9464'), ('close', '0.9575')]),
                     ]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the names and the values. With a list comprehension:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ordered_dictionary = [OrderedDict(zip(names, subl)) for subl in list_of_lists]
```

which gives:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([OrderedDict(zip(names, subl)) for subl in list_of_lists])
[OrderedDict([('date', '20010103'), ('open', '0.9507'), ('high', '0.9569'), ('low', '0.9262'), ('close', '0.9271')]),
 OrderedDict([('date', '20010104'), ('open', '0.9271'), ('high', '0.9515'), ('low', '0.9269'), ('close', '0.9507')]),
 OrderedDict([('date', '20010105'), ('open', '0.9507'), ('high', '0.9591'), ('low', '0.9464'), ('close', '0.9575')])]
```

Comment: Thank you! Clear and elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but I thought I'd suggest a `namedtuple` solution as an alternative to OrderedDict that would work well in this situation:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Bar = namedtuple('Bar', ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close'])

bars = [Bar(date, o, h, l, c) for date, o, h, l, c in list_of_lists]

>>> bars
[Bar(date='20010103', open='0.9507', high='0.9569', low='0.9262', close='0.9271'),
 Bar(date='20010104', open='0.9271', high='0.9515', low='0.9269', close='0.9507'),
 Bar(date='20010105', open='0.9507', high='0.9591', low='0.9464', close='0.9575')]

>>> bars[2].date
'20010105'

>>> bars[2].close
'0.9575'
```

Even better, one could use dictionary comprehension with the date as the key:

```
Bar = namedtuple('Bar', ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close'])

bars = {date: Bar(o, h, l, c) for date, o, h, l, c in list_of_lists}

>>> bars
{'20010103': Bar(open='0.9507', high='0.9569', low='0.9262', close='0.9271'),
 '20010104': Bar(open='0.9271', high='0.9515', low='0.9269', close='0.9507'),
 '20010105': Bar(open='0.9507', high='0.9591', low='0.9464', close='0.9575')}

>>> bars['20010105']
Bar(open='0.9507', high='0.9591', low='0.9464', close='0.9575')

>>> bars['20010105'].close
'0.9575'
```